# Как отправить фото и текст в одном сообщении

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Есть бот, который принимает от пользователя сообщение и отсылает его в закрытый чат, так же с фото. Как сделать, чтобы бот отправлял одним сообщением фото и текст, полученный от пользователя в закрытый чат.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def send_message(message):
    if len(message.text) > 15:
        bot.send_message(chat_id='MY_CHAT_ID', text=message.text)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Thank you for your order')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo_id(message):
    photo1 = max(message.photo, key=lambda x: x.height)
    bot.send_photo(chat_id='MY_CHAT_ID', photo=photo1.file_id)
```

Comment: В `bot.send_photo` добавь `caption=` и передавай туда текст сообщение

Comment: Не помогло отсылается только фото. Это нужно делать в одном хендлере? Можете сбросить код?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный хэндлер будет пересылать фото и подпись к фото

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
def photo_id(message):
    photo1 = max(message.photo, key=lambda x: x.height)
    bot.send_photo(chat_id='MY_CHAT_ID', photo=photo1.file_id, caption=message.caption)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]