# Python telebot как сделать чтобы при отправке фото так же писался текст

Tags: python, telebot, photo

Как сделать, чтобы при отправке фото так же писался и текст?

```html
def func(message):
    if (message.text == "Прикольные картинки"):
     mem = [
         "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-62/s/v1/ig2/k1bsooyQQwiaG7IR3OIvR6g5MpiV8-rV7gYpZQkeuVEGcMYBrgDibpp6fbbbklKcbyE6o4zyT0Sw5iSoag_f2qv5.jpg?size=540x920&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
         "https://sun3.tele2-nn.userapi.com/s/v1/ig2/k_vMWJ9Pc9VvdahlAriXccnG_Xdv0Cp4N_S-Z5dD9mTHCaBwQ4EEMk0jAXA2c1-UkzT_tMy7xPsKAUFN5WfxQ_U6.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
         "https://sun9-north.userapi.com/sun9-84/s/v1/ig2/D9ds1eMljPLrAtye2Jj0x04nCdygkTMyoGOThYQnVHnurgsQjlnP1U07MCw0czhQ6WgFfqJi4uEUmoGuprukcBc9.jpg?size=606x326&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
         "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-56/s/v1/ig2/5s07VWsHS_t2NI_6N3JDmee1mfARYrjCpaq85Pp6cvrT81-F_AEXrCVCZ2-4tDB77ltqga3Opsg6FCLKJPeorL8B.jpg?size=450x600&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
         "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-8/s/v1/ig2/YLZzeuRyyV0TfpPPvYuIyJ8aLdsB8PS0MwfbBEKRtHMNeK4wL5jBS1JBQcTw-gxbBcCZ2qT3MfD6uUJHwVr1JEg_.jpg?size=300x573&quality=95&type=album.jpg",
         "https://sun9-west.userapi.com/sun9-5/s/v1/ig2/Uz8RjtL84Ps3q1QK1tjgGHKP8Bc4DxPmXWDlZ32izYp236o6raItYEXJnRDUSXDQvvrCaZD8qXBQTsiIv-EQu-m9.jpg?size=1200x1600&quality=95&type=album.jpg"
           ]
     bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, random.choice(mem))
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отправить фото и текст в одном сообщении](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1444912/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b8-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, random.choice(mem), caption="text")
```